# Twitter Bootstrap - Using Icons

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and having problems displaying the icons. I am trying to recreate one of the examples here: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/#examples

Here is my code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<div class="control-group">
    <p><i class="icon-camera-retro icon-large"></i> icon-camera-retro</p>
    <p><i class="icon-camera-retro icon-2x"></i> icon-camera-retro</p>
    <p><i class="icon-camera-retro icon-3x"></i> icon-camera-retro</p>
    <p><i class="icon-camera-retro icon-4x"></i> icon-camera-retro</p>
</div>
```

The icons do not appear at all; do I need to link to any icon image file or anything like that? I am testing in Firefox, but the Font-Awesome example site does load properly so I'm pretty sure the browser choice isn't the problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Make sure the path to the font files inside font-awesome.min.css is correct for your setup.

Comment: Have you changed fonts folder path? If you did, you should update your fonts css file

Comment: Unless there's a specific reason you're using relative URLs for your files stick to "absolute" - that way, they will always be found wherever you call them from, eg: `/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Firebug installed? You should check for 404 errors in the Net tab, from your description I'm guessing you didn't place the font files in you server in the correct location.

If you look at the 1st few lines of [font-awesome.css](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/css/font-awesome.css), you'll see the following definition:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.0.1');
  src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.0.1') format('embedded-   opentype'),
       url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.0.1') format('woff'),
       url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.0.1') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Make sure to download the files referenced in the CSS ([which you can find here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/font)) to your server and place it under **assets/font**.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you copy the Font Awesome "font" folder into your "assets" folder.

Font Awesome **overrides** twitter bootstrap "icons" that uses the **../img/glyphicons-halflings.png**

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    display: inline;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    line-height: normal;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background-image: none;
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

It will need the font-files to render the icons on the page ;)